# sending bitmaps over tcp in c#

Tags: c#, image, tcp, bitmap, networkstream

iam trying to send an image continously but somehow it is not working. the problem is,that sometimes when the receiver tries to read the size into the string it reads some unknown 6 bytes. I dont know where they come from because i thougth that the networkstream is empty when all the bytes are read.

```
/// <summary>
/// This is the class that captures the screen and sends it
/// </summary>
public class TCPClient
{
    TcpClient me;
    bool lauf = true;
    NetworkStream ns;
    Thread mainThread;
    int ind = 0;

    public TCPClient()
    {
        mainThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(sendThread));
        mainThread.Start();
    }

    public void sendThread()
    {
        try
        {
            me = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1",16500);
            ns = me.GetStream();
            while (lauf)
            {
                MemoryStream tempMS = this.getScreen();
                byte[] package = tempMS.ToArray();
                String tempS = "" + package.Length;
                byte[] tempBS = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tempS);
                ns.Write(tempBS, 0, tempBS.Length);
                ns.Write(package, 0, package.Length);    
                Console.WriteLine("Paket gesendet " + package.Length);
                //package = null;
                Console.WriteLine("Memoryuse: " + Convert.ToDouble(((Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64))/1024)/1024);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                //Die ms müssen für die Steuerung evtl runtergeregelt werden,da sonst eine komfortable steuerung nicht möglich ist
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            Console.ReadKey();
            mainThread.Abort();
            ns.Close();
            me.Close(); 
        }
    }

    public MemoryStream getScreen() 
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height);

        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            graphics.CopyFromScreen(0,0,0,0,bitmap.Size);
            Cursors.Default.Draw(graphics,new Rectangle(Cursor.Position,Cursor.Current.Size));
            graphics.Dispose();
        }

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Save(memoryStream,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

        bitmap.Dispose();
        //memoryStream.Flush();
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        return memoryStream;
    }

    public void setLauf(bool pLauf)
    {
        lauf = pLauf;
    }
}

public class TcpReceiver
{
    private TcpClient me;
    private MainForm MF;
    private bool lauf = true;
    private Thread recieveThread;

    public TcpReceiver(MainForm tMF)
    {
        MF = tMF;
        recieveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(recieveImage));
        recieveThread.Start();
    }

    public void recieveImage()
    {
        try
        {           
            TcpListener tempListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any,16500);
            tempListener.Start();
            me = tempListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            //MF.newClient(me.Client.AddressFamily.ToString());
            NetworkStream ns = me.GetStream();

            while(lauf)
            {
                if (ns.DataAvailable)
                {
                    byte[] tempSA = new byte[6];
                    ns.Read(tempSA, 0, tempSA.Length);
                    String tempS = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tempSA);
                    int size = Int32.Parse(tempS);
                    byte[] tempBA = new byte[size];
                    ns.Read(tempBA, 0, tempBA.Length);

                    MemoryStream tempMS = new MemoryStream(tempBA);
                    Bitmap tempBitmap = new Bitmap(tempMS);
                    MF.showData(tempBitmap);

                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

    public void setLauf(bool tLauf)
    {
        lauf = tLauf;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try flushing the network stream after writing to it?

Comment: @kuba Nah.. It's sending stuff alright, just not understandable stuff.

Comment: You should still do it. In the writer, call .Flush after the writes. And also in the reader, you *must* check the return value of .Read, because it may read only less then then number you tried to read.

Comment: In the reader, get the return value of `ns.Read(tempBA, 0, tempBA.Length);` and do a Console.WriteLine with that value. Probably you will find out, that it's different from what you expect.

Comment: I don't like how you write the package length bytes after casting it to string. Try using StreamWriter to write it as an int/long. In general, you should use StreamWriter for easier writing into streams.

Comment: i thought that the networkstream is empty after all data is read but obviously it isnt?

Comment: Read this doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx, specifically this part: "Return Value
The total number of bytes read into the buffer. This can be less than the number of bytes requested if that many bytes are not currently available, or zero (0) if the end of the stream has been reached."

Comment: I think your problem is this: 'System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tempS)' <- you are trying to encode a number into a byte representation and I don't think that this is a bijection (at least it is not fixed length) .... try using a 'BinaryFormatter' instead!

Comment: i worked out,that it does not read all the bytes out of the stream. how do i force it to read all the bytes?